# Passing image from collectionview(based on json)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have 2 json responses in this format...

```
 //1           {
                    "product_id": "22",
                    "product_name": "asd",
                    "product_description": "Test",
                    "rating_count": 0,
                    "product_images": [
                        {
                            "id": "973",
                            "image": "http://myappp.com/uploads/products/16_546_4_image",
                            "is_default": "0"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "988",
                            "image": "http://myappp.com/uploads/products/123_45_67_image",
                            "is_default": "0"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "989",
                            "image": "http://myappp.com/uploads/products/123_45_6_image",
                            "is_default": "1"
                        }
                    ]
                },

//2                {
                    "product_id": "5",
                    "product_name": "cake",
                    "product_description": "The boss and Anchor Hocking are you doing today hope",
                    "rating_count": 0,
                    "product_images": [
                        {
                            "id": "962",
                            "image": "http://myappp.com/uploads/products/123_546_image",
                            "is_default": "1"
                        }
                    ]
            }
```

These are associated with 2 collectionview cells. Here I have an array called `product_images` with some parameters. Now I have a collectionview on which I'm displaying only those images from the url which have an `is_default` value of 1. I'm doing it like so...

```
 for anItem in productData {
  var productImages :[ProductImage] = []  //ProductImage is a struct having parameters myid, url and isDefault

if let images = anItem["product_images"] as? [[String:String]] {

     if let defaultImage = images.first(where: {$0["is_default"] == "1"}) {
                let productImage = ProductImage(myId: defaultImage["id"]!,
                                                url: URL(string: defaultImage["image"]!)!,
                                                isDefault: true)
                productImages.append(productImage)
            } } }
```

So if a collection view item shows an image then that image has an `is_default` value of 1. But each cell will also have associated with it the other images also with `is_default` value of 0 and other parameters like `product_id`, `product_name` etc. But only thing is what is shown in the collection view is the image with an `is_default` value of 1.

Now what I want to achieve is when I click on a collectionview cell I want to pass to another view not just the image shown on the cell but also the other images associated with a cell with an `is_default` value of 0. So if have 2 collectionview cells and each of them has the values of 1st and 2nd json(given above) respectively, then on the click of the first collectionviewcell I should be able to show 3 images and on the click of the 2nd collectionviewcell I should be able to show just 1 image.

Hope somebody can help...

Comment: How are you using two jsons ? they are in one array ?

Comment: yes. They are in one array. The images are in one array as given above like this `productImages.append(productImage)`

Comment: so can't you get one whole dictionary based on indexPath ? I am confused with what you want to pass ? The whole single object with product_id and product_images or some part of it ?

Comment: I just want to pass the images and none of the id, name or other values. In order to show the images in the collectionview, the code snippet given in the question has been used which takes only the image with `is_default` value of 1. But when I click on the collection view cell, I want to pass all images (i.e. with `is_default` of 0 & 1) to another view.

Comment: can't you pass product_images array ?

Comment: Right now `productImages` array has all the images from the json and that too the ones with an `is_default` value of 1. But when I select a collectionview cell I want to pass all images associated with that particular cell with an `is_default` value of 0 and 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159874/discussion-between-sharad-chauhan-and-bvt).